# Windows 10 login extremely slow unless on airplane mode

Tags: windows-10, login

When I log in to my windows 10 laptop, it usually takes about 3 seconds if I am at the office. When I am home, it takes about 5 minutes. I have noticed that if I am on airplane mode, the log in time goes back to 3 seconds. So, I am thinking that the laptop is trying to communicate with something on a work server, and waits a long time for it to time-out. Is there a way to check if this is the case?

Comment: I don't know if there is, but at home I'd use a local account, not the one known on your office's domain.

Comment: do you restore network drives at login?